# Keeping the background colour when adding buttons to a grid/frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, background, tkinter

The problem I'm having is keeping my background colour when adding buttons to a frame, as soon as I run the module the background colour disappears, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Heres me code:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')

var=tk.StringVar()

Frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
Frame1.configure(background='light blue',height='300',width='500')
Frame1.grid(row='0',column='0')

Frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
Frame2.configure(background='grey',height='300',width='500')
Frame2.grid(row='0',column='1')

Frame3 = tk.Frame(root)
Frame3.configure(background='grey',height='300',width='500')
Frame3.grid(row='1',column='0')

Frame4 = tk.Frame(root)
Frame4.configure(background='light blue',height='300',width='500')
Frame4.grid(row='1',column='1')


def PrintOrder():
    LabelOrder = tk.Label(Frame3,text="DONUT ORDER")
    LabelOrder.grid(row='0',column='0')
    return

Button1 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Apple Cinnamon",height='2',width='15',command=PrintOrder).grid(row='0',column='0')
Button2 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Strawberry",height='2',width='15',command=PrintOrder).grid(row='0',column='1')
Button3 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Custard",height='2',width='15',command=PrintOrder).grid(row='0',column='2')
Button4 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Sugar Ring",height='2',width='15',command=PrintOrder).grid(row='1',column='0')
Button5 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Chocolate Caramel",height='2',width='15',command=PrintOrder).grid(row='1',column='1')
Button6 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Lemon Circle",height='2',width='15',command=PrintOrder).grid(row='1',column='2')
Button7 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Blueberry Blaster",height='2',width='15',command=PrintOrder).grid(row='2',column='0')
Button8 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Strawberry Surprise",height='2',width='15',command=PrintOrder).grid(row='2',column='1')
Button9 = tk.Button(Frame1,text="Simple Sugar",height='2',width='15',command=PrintOrder).grid(row='2',column='2')

Label1 = tk.Label(Frame2,text="Donut special 6 for the price of 5").grid(row='0',column='0')
Button10 = tk.Button(Frame2,text="SPECIAL",height='5',width='20').grid(row='1',column='0')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your frame still has its background color. You can see this pretty easily if you give it a distinct color so that it will show (eg: "red"), and add padding between the buttons (eg: tk.Button(...).grid(..., padx=10, pady=10). I think the only thing that is happening is that there is no space between the buttons for the color to show through, and the default behavior is for the frame to shrink (or grow) to fit its contents.

Other problems include the fact that you aren't giving any rows or columns a weight, so they won't grow or shrink as the main window grows an shrinks. Also, you don't have the `sticky` attribute set for the frames, so they won't fill the grid cell that they occupy. Add `sticky="nsew"` to where you grid the frames and you'll likely see more color.

A rule of thumb when using grid is to always set the `sticky` attribute for each item, and to give at least one row and one column a weight of 1 (one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid_propagate(0)` on your frames. With this, the frame's size is not adjusted to the widgets' size.

On your code, I used the next line to keep the size of Frame1:

```
Frame1.grid_propagate(0)
```

You can check this:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method

grid_propagate(flag) [#]

Enables or disables geometry propagation. When enabled, a grid manager connected to this widget attempts to change the size of the widget whenever a child widget changes size. Propagation is always enabled by default.

flag
True to enable propagation.